# Переменные в cursor.execute

Tags: python, oracle

Хочу запускать sql-запрос питоновским файлом, подставля в запрос объявленную в коде пайтона переменную.
Если записать sql-запрос в самом файле пайтона, все ок, но если запрос вынести в отдельный файл, моя переменная в запрос не попадает.

Вот так работает:

```
kod = '5, 7'
...
cursor.execute(f"""SELECT docname from TABLE_1
where kod in ({kod})""")
```

Но если вынести этот запрос в отдельный файл 1.sql:

```
kod = '5, 7'

with open('1.sql', 'r') as sql:
    query = sql.readlines()
query = " ".join(query)
...
cursor.execute(f"""query""")
```

...выдает ошибку "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

Подскажите, плиз, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Убрал тэг. СУБД Оракл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем `sql` файле запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```sql
SELECT docname from TABLE_1
where kod in (%s);
```

Вызов в коде `python` так:

```py
items = [5, 7]

with open('1.sql', 'r') as sql:
    query = sql.read()

cursor.execute(query, [items])
```

> *Вообще ни разу не лучшая практика использовать `f` строки для форматирования запросов:*
> *1. Не удобно.* 
> *2. Не безопасно.*

Comment: СУБД Оракл, пробовал в запросе использовать :kod (там, где у Вас %s), но тогда принимает только одно значение. На список значений ругается *ORA-01484: arrays can only be bound to PL/SQL statements*, если несколько значений передаю как строку, ругается *ORA-01722: invalid number*

Comment: @АлексейМайборода, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808684/python-cx-oracle-oracle-query-with-conditions-including-a-list-of-valuesin

Comment: @АлексейМайборода, ответ поправил. Дал ссылку на вопрос, где видна реализация `in`

Comment: Решилось так:
`SELECT docname from TABLE_1
where kod in (%s)

items = '5, 7'`


`with open('1.sql', 'r') as sql:
    query = sql.readlines()
query = " ".join(query)

cursor.execute(f"""{query}""" % items)`

Спасибо за помощь!